# Return reoccuring regex matches with python

Tags: python, regex

I have a string:

```
SomeTextSomeTextASomeThingBSomeTextSomeTextASomeThingElseBSomeText
```

I want to have the Strings SomeThing and SomeThingElse string returned because they are bracketed with A and B and assuming SomeText does not contain any A ... B occurences.

Any hint would be highly appreciated.

Here's what I tried, but it doesn't work:

```
import re

string = 'SomeTextSomeTextASomeThingBSomeTextSomeTextASomeThingElseBSomeText'
regex='(A.*B)'
```

I guess neither the regex is correct, nor do I know how to access the matches. Is it match of `finditer` or…?

Answer (score 3):

Try using `re.findall`:

```
>>> print re.findall('A(.*?)B', s)
['SomeThing', 'SomeThingElse']
```

See it working online: [ideone](http://ideone.com/20QrS)

Note the question mark. Without it the matching is done greedily - it will consume as many characters as possible.